# How to set up postgresql in vpn network

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql on a server which I connect to via VPN. When I try to connect to the database server(from my local pgAdmin III), I get the message, that I am missing the right to access postgresql.

What settings do I have to change in order to be able to connect?

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your vpn-setup. If you're using routing rather than bridging, you need to allow access for your IP or for your net to access the DB. See http://www.grc.com/vpn/routing.htm for an explanation.